# Handling repeating Attributes and its value in xml using XSLT code

Tags: xml, xslt, attributes, xslt-1.0

I have an xml wit repeating ITEM segment and its attributes needs to be handled using XSLT 1.0

```
<TransportationRequestQuotation>
<Item>
    <GrossWeightTransportationQuantity>
        <unitCode>KG</unitCode>
        <text>60</text>
    </GrossWeightTransportationQuantity>
    <InsuranceDeclaredAmount>
        <currencyCode>SAR</currencyCode>
        <text>5000</text>
    </InsuranceDeclaredAmount>
    </Item>
<Item>
    <GrossWeightTransportationQuantity>
        <unitCode>KG</unitCode>
        <text>80</text>
    </GrossWeightTransportationQuantity>
    <InsuranceDeclaredAmount>
        <currencyCode>SAR</currencyCode>
        <text>5000</text>
    </InsuranceDeclaredAmount>
</Item>
</TransportationRequestQuotation>
```

The Expected xml is as below using the XSLT code:

```
<TransportationRequestQuotation>
<Item>
    <GrossWeightTransportationQuantity unitCode="KG">60</GrossWeightTransportationQuantity>
    <InsuranceDeclaredAmount currencyCode="SAR">5000</InsuranceDeclaredAmount>
</Item>
<Item>
    <GrossWeightTransportationQuantity unitCode="KG">80</GrossWeightTransportationQuantity>
    <InsuranceDeclaredAmount currencyCode="SAR">5000</InsuranceDeclaredAmount>
</Item>
</TransportationRequestQuotation>
```

I have used the below codes but unable to get the desired output :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ns0="http://sap.com/xi/SAPGlobal20/Global">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>



<xsl:template match="GrossWeightTransportationQuantity">
        <xsl:element name="GrossWeightTransportationQuantity">
            <xsl:for-each select="*">
                <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" >
                    <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="InsuranceDeclaredAmount">
        <xsl:element name="InsuranceDeclaredAmount">
            <xsl:for-each select="*">
                <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" >
                    <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Requesting to help me handling repeating values in ITEM attributes level .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is apply-templates to children of `GrossWeightTransportationQuantity` and `InsuranceDeclaredAmount` except for `text` and change those to attributes. Then just output the value of `text`.

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="GrossWeightTransportationQuantity|InsuranceDeclaredAmount">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::text)]"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="text"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="GrossWeightTransportationQuantity/*|InsuranceDeclaredAmount/*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```